# Kafka JDBC Connect (Source and Sink) and Informix

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, informix

is there any way to convert ":" to "." in a query constructed by jdbc connector?

*"SELECT * FROM  database  :  user  :  table  WHERE  database  :  user  :  table "*

**connector configuration:**

```
"name": "jdbc_source_connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url" : "jdbc:informix-sqli://IP:PORT/databasa:informixserver=oninit;user=user;password=password",
    "topic.prefix" : "table-",
    "poll.interval.ms" : "100000",
    "mode" : "incrementing",
    "table.whitelist" : "table",
    "query.suffix" : ";",
    "incrementing.column.name" : "lp"
```

**ERROR:**

```
[2021-02-03 14:03:02,809] INFO Begin using SQL query: SELECT * FROM  database  :  user  :  table  WHERE  database  :  user  :  table : lp  > ? ORDER B
Y  database  :  user  :  table : lp  ASC ; (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier:164)
[2021-02-03 14:03:02,853] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table="database "." user "." table", query='null', top
icPrefix='database-', incrementingColumn='lp', timestampColumns=[]}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:404)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: A syntax error has occurred.
```

**connector session:**

```
informix database:/usr/informix$ onstat -g ses 544271

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC13 -- On-Line -- Up 60 days 18:26:06 -- 4985440 Kbytes

session           effective                                               #RSAM    total      used       dynamic
id       user     user      tty      pid      hostname                    threads  memory     memory     explain
544271   user      -         -        1266352  kafkahost                  1        172032     102672     off

Program :
Thread[id:175, name:task-thread-jdbc_source_connector_database, path:/app/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/plugins/kafka-connect-jdbc-10.0.1/lib/jdbc-4.50.4.1.jar]

tid      name     rstcb            flags    curstk   status
583042   sqlexec  7000000437451a8  Y--P---  6224     cond wait  netnorm   -

Memory pools    count 2
name         class addr              totalsize  freesize   #allocfrag #freefrag
544271       V     70000004f6c7040  167936     68592      113        35
544271*O0    V     700000065ad0040  4096       768        1          1

name           free       used           name           free       used
overhead       0          6656           scb            0          144
opentable      0          11352          filetable      0          1040
log            0          16536          temprec        0          22688
keys           0          816            gentcb         0          1592
ostcb          0          3472           sqscb          0          25128
hashfiletab    0          552            osenv          0          2056
sqtcb          0          9336           fragman        0          640
sapi           0          144            udr            0          520

sqscb info
scb              sqscb            optofc   pdqpriority optcompind  directives
7000000343d3360  700000039194028  0        0           0           1

Sess       SQL            Current            Iso Lock       SQL  ISAM F.E.
Id         Stmt type      Database           Lvl Mode       ERR  ERR  Vers  Explain
544271     -              database                CR  Not Wait   0    0    9.28  Off

Last parsed SQL statement :
  SELECT * FROM  database  :  user  :  table  WHERE  database  :  user  :  table :
    lp  > ? ORDER BY  database  :  user  :  table : lp  ASC
```

Comment: Why are you writing the query using the non-native notation?  Is that truly normal?  Informix uses `[database[@server]:][owner.]tablename` to identify a table natively (so `database@server:owner.tablename` is OK, as is `database@server:tablename`, `database:owner.tablename`, `database:tablename`, `owner.tablename` or plain `tablename`). Things can get tricky when identifying columns, but the notation basically uses a dot to separate the table name from the column name.  I don't know anything about Kafka (and little enough about JDBC), but this feels a bit like "Doctor, Doctor, it hurts …".

Comment: the thing is, this query is generated automatically by the connector and the connector inserts ":" instead of "."

Comment: Can you use the `query` option in Kafka to specify the syntax you need for Informix? https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/configuration_options.html

Comment: Yes.  the query option works fine

Comment: Thank you Brian Hughes !

Answer (score 2):

so, the only workaround is to add the query option to the connector configuration

config after modifications:

```
"name": "jdbc_source_connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url" : "jdbc:informix-sqli://IP:PORT/databasa:informixserver=oninit;user=user;password=password",
    "topic.prefix" : "table-tablename",
    "poll.interval.ms" : "100000",
    "mode" : "incrementing",
    "query" : "select * from table ",
    "incrementing.column.name" : "lp"
```