# How connector-source works with "query" and "mode": timestamp+incrementing

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Can someone explain to me how the connector source works using "query" and the "mode": timestamp+incrementing?
Because it works perfectly when the query is small but for many records it becomes impossible.
From what I see, it re-runs the entire query over and over again.

This is my source connector:

```
    {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:informix-sqli://ip:port/sis:informixserver=mibase",
        "connection.user":"informix", 
        "connection.password":"pass",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM my_vw",
        "topic.prefix": "novedades",
        "db.timezone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
        "dialect.name": "GenericDatabaseDialect",
        "timestamp.granularity": "connect_logical",
        "poll.interval.ms": "10000",
        "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
        "schema.pattern": "informix",
        "timestamp.column.name": "last_date",
        "incrementing.column.name": "id",
        "validate.non.null": false,

        "numeric.mapping":"best_fit",
        "transforms": "copyFieldToKey,extractKeyFromStruct,removeKeyFromValue",
        "transforms.copyFieldToKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.copyFieldToKey.fields": "id",
        "transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.field": "id",
        "transforms.removeKeyFromValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
        "transforms.removeKeyFromValue.blacklist": "id",
        "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter"

}
```

The filters work well because it only brings me the changes and/or new records, but apparently it reruns the entire query and if it has millions of records, that total is read over and over again.

Comment: As mentioned before, you shouldn't be using `SELECT *` with `query` anyway. That option is only to be used when you need a very specific subset of columns, or pre-filter, or custom join, etc. Even with genetic dialect, you should be able to use `table.whitelist` with only one table, or put table name in the connection url

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't understand why you say that I shouldn't use `SELECT *` with `query`?
Using query is the only solution to make the connector work using an Informix database. The table.whitelist option does not work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029521/kafka-jdbc-connect-source-and-sink-and-informix


https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/576

Comment: I've never used informix. And dialect shouldn't really matter. In my opinion, `SELECT *` should be the default prefix of any dialect. If that's a bug, then so be it

Comment: In any case, "for many records", you should always add LIMIT to your queries